# loginctl enable-linger error Could not enable linger: Access denied

Tags: server, 20.04, systemd

I have 2 Ubuntu 20.04 servers. One of them gives me this error.

```
Could not enable linger: Access denied
```

when running

```
loginctl enable-linger
```

The other server doesn't raise any errors. I did a bit of research, but I could not find a solution to my problem. Checking the version of the system installed on the servers I found out that the server that is raising the error has systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) (newer) and the one that is working fine has systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.22) (older).

I tried to verbose the command `loginctl`, but I didn't find out how to do it.

I found the package of the older version [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/245.4-4ubuntu3.22), but I don't know how to downgrade if it's actually possible to downgrade.

Comment: Does `loginctl user-status` work? How about `loginctl show-user "$LOGNAME" --property=Linger`?